# Load iframe only after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm trying to embed a video using an iframe, but it slows down the page loading speed.

How can I make the iframe only load once the user has clicked play now?

```html
<li class="embed-list">
    <?php echo $title; ?> 
    <span class="play">Play Now</span>
    <div class="embed-video">
        <iframe src="http://www.thevideo.me/embed-<?php echo $link; ?>-640x360.html" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</li>
```

```js
jQuery('.embed-list').click(function () {
    $this = jQuery(this);
    $this.siblings().find('.embed-video').css('display', 'none');
    $this.find('.embed-video').css('display', 'block');
    $this.siblings('.embed-list').find('span').replaceWith("<span class='play'>Play Now</span>");
    $this.find('span').replaceWith("<span class='play'>Playing</span>");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a few ways to solve this. Raw JavaScript versus JavaScript aside, you have a choice to make:

You could 1) load the frame with the page normally, but hide the `<iframe>` until the user clicks Play Now. This would give the effect of the user seeing the loaded video or page immediately in many cases.

Or you could 2) append the `<iframe>` to the DOM when the user clicks Play Now, effectively causing the video or page to load in the iframe which takes time.

Because you've tagged this with jQuery, here's how you could perform the first way outlined above using jQuery:

**Hides the container and toggles it**

```
$(function(){
  var $play_button = $('.play');
  var $iframe_container = $('.embed-video');

  $iframe_container.hide();
  $play_button.on('click',function(){
    $iframe_container.toggle();
    });
});
```

Or, to use the code block you mentioned, you could do this:

```
$(function() {
  var $video = $('.embed-video').hide();
  jQuery('.embed-list').click(function() {
    $this = jQuery(this);
    $video.show();
    $this.siblings('.embed-list').find('span').replaceWith("<span class='play'>Play Now</span>");
    $this.find('span').replaceWith("<span class='play'>Playing</span>");
  });
});
```

See it in action here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OVEKwR

Comment: If this solution worked for you, please consider marking it as the correct answer.